# React app doesn't compile when run in a docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I'm currently trying to run my react app in a docker container but for some reason it can't resolve the dependencies when I run it.

To create the docker container I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and I ignore node_modules in my .dockerignore

I then run it using this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
        
    react-app:
        image: react-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        stdin_open: true
        volumes:
        - /app/node_modules
        ports:
        - "3000:3000/tcp"
```

These are the docker logs which show the compile error:

```
webpack output is served from
Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in '/app/src'
Compiling...
Failed to compile.

./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in '/app/src'
```

I have this dependency in the "dependencies" section of my package.json:

```
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5"
```

and the app compiles when I run it outside of the docker container.

If I exec into the docker container I can see that /app/node_modules/@types/react-router-dom does exist so it looks like npm install isn't the issue. Am I missing something in my compose file? Or am I importing it incorrectly in the code? My import statement is:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are `'react-router-dom'` modules? Maybe you need to add `COPY` line to your dockerfile and copy App.tsk to /app

Comment: App.tsx is in /app/src/App.tsx and the react-router-dom module is in /app/node_modules/@types/react-router-dom. This matches the structure of the project when it's not inside a docker container so I would expect it to compile...

Comment: The `volumes:` directive you have explicitly tells Docker to use an old version of your `node_modules` directory, from the first time you ran the container.  Does deleting that `volumes:` block (and using the `node_modules` tree in the image) improve things?

Comment: Took the container down, pruned the volumes, removed the volume block from the compose as you suggested and brought the container back up again but unfortunately it still has the same issue,

Comment: Do you actually have a dependency on `react-router-dom` in your `package.json`, or just its Typescript declarations?

Comment: Just @types/react-router-dom. I guess I assumed that would bring in the actual dependency itself, but are you saying it may not? Seems strange that it compiles outside of docker if that's the case.